# OptParse, whitespace and bash

Tags: python, bash, echo, optparse

I have a weird issue with bash / optparse. I need to pass string to my python script when string is defined.

I use following code:

```
./lol.py `if [ -n "$URL" ]; then echo -u \"$URL\"; fi`
```

and here is python script:

```
def main():
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-u", dest="url")
    opts, args = parser.parse_args()
    print opts.url
```

When I test my bash expression it appears to be working:

```
user@fomce02:~$ URL="http://lol.com/my project/"
user@fomce02:~$ echo `if [ -n "$URL" ]; then echo -u \"$URL\"; fi`
-u "http://lol.com/my project/"
```

However when I run python script with an argument

```
user@fomce02:~$ ./lol.py `if [ -n "$URL" ]; then echo -u "$URL"; fi`
http://lol.com/my
```

it truncates part of string after whitespace.

Could you explain why it is happening and how to get it work?

Comment: If the python version you are using 2.7 or above it is recommended to use the module 'argparse' . The usage of module optparse is deprecated (http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the quotes you are sending to the script are *literal*, not *syntactic*. That means `lol.py` receives the parameters `"http://lol.com/my` and `project/"`. If you want to pass the result of a command as a *single* parameter you have to use syntactic quotes around the code:

```
./lol.py "$(if [ -n "$URL" ]; then echo -u "$URL"; fi)"
```

Also fixed the backticks - If you're using Bash it's highly recommended to use `$()`. Note that the [quoting context](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) is *different* inside and outside the command substitution, so there's no danger of the outer quotes affecting the inner quotes.